# How exactly Convolution2D layer works in Keras?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I want to write own convolution layer same as Convolution2D.
How it works in Keras? 
For example, if Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(3,226,226)
Which equation will be for output data?

Comment: Keras is built on top of Tensorflow and Theano. What do you mean by "to write own convolution"? Do you want to implement a convolutional layer with means of Tensorflow/Theano or from scratch?

Comment: I want to write own cnn lib, but for test use pre-trainded Keras or Tensorflow model. I want to figure out how these libs use input data and weights in convolution layer to get output data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you input image shape is (266, 266, 3)[tf]/(3, 266, 266)[th], and the filter number is 64, and the kernel size is 3x3, and for padding, I think the default padding is 1, and the default stride is 1.

So, the output is 266x266x64.

```
output_width=output_height=(width – filter + 2*padding)/stride + 1
```

in your code, the width=266, the filter=3, the padding=1, and stride=1.

If you have any trouble understanding the basic concepts, I think you can read [this cs231n post](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/) for more information.

For how to understanding the process of conv, click [here](http://cs231n.github.io/assets/conv-demo/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Keras is not doing a convolution in conv2d.
In order to speed up the process, the convolution operation is converted into a matrix (row-per-column) multiplication.
More info [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-comprehensive-introduction-to-different-types-of-convolutions-in-deep-learning-669281e58215), at chapter 6.